# Change the Jquery Tools Tab Slideshow clickable area

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/slideshow.htm

Can I change this so that the panels are not clickable? make it only navigations are clickable?

Comment: Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/shavindra/j7UcM/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `$(".images div").unbind('click');` at thr bottom of the script, right after `}).slideshow();`

Comment: Thanks for making it clearer Answer is here http://jsfiddle.net/shavindra/j7UcM/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div").unbind("click");
```